# Nexus OSS auto stop

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

My environment is Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and java version 1.7.0_79, Apache Maven 3.0.5, nexus 2.10.0-02.

I had execute ./nexus start and it seems be ok. But ten seconds later, i check the status of nexus, it is not running. And i always can't visit the site "http://localhost:8081/nexus".

```html
root@iZ94lnn03ejZ:/opt/nexus-2.10.0-02/bin# ./nexus start
****************************************
WARNING - NOT RECOMMENDED TO RUN AS ROOT
****************************************
Starting Nexus OSS...
Started Nexus OSS.
root@iZ94lnn03ejZ:/opt/nexus-2.10.0-02/bin# ./nexus status
****************************************
WARNING - NOT RECOMMENDED TO RUN AS ROOT
****************************************
Nexus OSS is not running.
root@iZ94lnn03ejZ:/opt/nexus-2.10.0-02/bin#
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not run Nexus as root as the error message indicated. Beyond that you can check the log file in sonatype-work/nexus/logs/nexus.log to see what is going wrong at startup in detail.

Also you should use Java 1.8 and a newer version of Nexus (2.11.4 is latest at the moment).

**Update:** Evidently the log showed that the server is out of RAM so it must have been a very low spec virtual machine or server.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had found the log file in nexus-2.10.0-02 folder and the reason is :"The system is out of physical RAM or swap space"

Answer (score 0):

First check `#java -version`, if this command gives nothing then install Java: `yum install openjdk-8* -y`

Answer (score -1):

NO i think you need to give permissions to execute nexus repo.
i.e give chown 777 nexus-